# Python output and why

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

```
x = [10,20,30]

for i in x:
     print(i)
     x.append(40)
     x = [50,60]

print(x)
```

Output is :

```
10
20
30
40
[50,60]
```

Why is 20, 30, 40 coming? Not 50,60

Comment: When you assign `[50, 60]` to `x` inside the loop, you decouple it from the `x` used by the loop, which remains fixed at `[10, 20, 30, 40]`.  Try this:  `a = [1, 2]; b = [3, 4]; b.append[5]`.  You will end up with `a` being `[1, 2]` and `b` being `[3, 4, 5]`.  Two different lists.  This is no different.

Comment: I'd like to note that if you didn't do `x = [50,60]` and assigned `x` to a new object (as in if you appended like you did with `40`). It won't do what you expect, it will be an infinite loop adding `40,50,60` to `x` over and over again: `[10,20,30,40,50,60,40,50,60,40,50,60, ...]`

Comment: you can't change the for loop iterator, if you want such thing we have while loops. for loop is for you know the number of iteration in advance

Answer (score 6):

The reason why this happens is because the **loop uses the list object** created in line 1. On line 5, you add 40 to this object, and then assign a **new object** to the x **variable**. The loop is still using the object you created earlier.

Comment: It's interesting that only in the first iteration `append` affects either version of `x`. If the new object assignment is removed, the loop will never complete, so without the assignment it would continue to append to the original `x`, I wonder what the `append` is actually doing.

Comment: @Deepstop Append modifies the value of the existing object reference on the `x` being used for the loop, rather than a entirely new object which no longer ties to the original reference the iterator is using.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek yes but only on the first iteration. If it did that on subsequent iterations the loop would never complete, which happens when `x = [50, 60]` is removed.

Comment: @Deepstop Yes I know. That's why I explained why in my comment to your question on what append is doing and why it's different then a new assignment and I've mentioned that in a comment on question.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I'm lost on your explanation but I the answer is that on the second iteration is appending to the new x which is then being replaced by new assignment. So a new new x is created on every iteration. My bad. Should have been obvious at the outset.

Answer (score 0):

variable i is pointing to old x address. you append 40 in old address once. the new x has different address which i is not pointing to. variable i is still pointing to old x address.

Extra:
if you remember when we pass list to function , we pass it by address not as value.  this is same concept.